# Qt-Creator CodeCompletion: C++ models exposing via Q_INVOKABLE to QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt-creator

Is there a change to get CodeCompletion running Qt-Creator with the following "design":

C++ Model app:

```
#define MODEL_ACCESSOR(method_name, model_member_)
    Q_INVOKABLE QObject* method_name() const 
    { 
        return model_member_; 
    }
...

MODEL_ACCESSOR(coffee, coffee_view_model_)

...

qml_app_engine_.rootContext()->setContextProperty("app", this);

...

qml_utils::owned_object(coffee_view_model_= new CoffeeModel(this));

...
```

Coffee:

```
class Coffee: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(int temperature READ temperature NOTIFY temperatureChanged)
```

QML:

```
Coffee{
    temperature: app.coffee().temperature
}
```

Problem in Qt-Creator:

Auto Completion works in the QML File for app.coffee()
But it cant resolve and autocomplete the propertys of the Coffee class.

At this point: "app.coffee()." it cant resolve the propertys.

Does anyone knows an Solution for that problem?

Comment: That is correct, because the return value of the invokables are QObject*, you should return the actual type of the member

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - but if the Q_INVOKABLE return is Coffee* Qt-Creator can't resolve it either...